# Date and Time Picker control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I tried to use the date with time picker control and I used the code from this link http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Implement-DateTimePicker-in-ASP.Net-using-jQuery-Plugin.aspx
when I click to change the time, automatically the time is scrolling either way when move the mouse anywhere on the screen.Is there any error in this code?

```
script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>").dynDateTime({

        showsTime: true,

        ifFormat: "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M",

        daFormat: "%l;%M %p, %e %m, %Y",

        align: "BR",

        electric: true,

        singleClick: true,

        displayArea: ".siblings('.dtcDisplayArea')",

        button: ".next()"

    });

});
```

Comment: It would be nice to tag `javascript` and `jquery`, too.

Comment: You've tagged this as C# and ASP.NET but you posted javascript and jquery code.

Answer (score 0):

Try electric: false instead. Here are the available settings:

https://code.google.com/p/dyndatetime/wiki/Home